# Was Jar Jar ever unbanished?

Tags: star-wars

In the beginning of the Phantom Menace, we know that everyone's favorite Gungan was banished from Otoh Gunga.  Later in the movie he becomes a General, helping resolve the differences between the Naboo and the Gungans, helping save Naboo from the Trade Federation, and later in the series he becomes a politician.

In the book *Aftermath, Empire's End* we see that Jar Jar is very much alive and well, but the adults hate him.  A boy asks him why and he says that he was banished a longo time ago.  Was this a second banishing after the events of RotS, or was his original banishment never removed?

Comment: The galaxy should hate him for his part in giving Palpatine emergency powers.  That and just being awful in general

Comment: No. The universe [has never forgiven him](http://geektyrant.com/news/rey-finn-and-poe-fight-jar-jar-binks-in-fan-made-comic-star-wars-episode-75)

Comment: I remember an episode of *The Clone Wars* in which Anakin, Kenobi, Dooku were captured by pirates. Republic ship was on mission to deliver ransom. The ship crashed and a senior politician died. Then, clone troopers asked Jar-Jar about next order as he was now most senior there. I almost killed myself that day.

Comment: @Machavity Haha.. Awesome!

Comment: "... everyone's favorite Gungan..."  buh buh buh...

Comment: "Yud say boom de gasser, den crashin der bosses heyblibber, den banished." Boss Nass doesn't seem like the kind of person who forgives a crashin of his heyblibber that easily.

Comment: He remains forever banished in real life, in any galaxy long ago and long in the future.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While Boss Nass never outright tells Jar Jar he's unbanished, the fact that he congratulates Binks and gives him a promotion makes it pretty clear.

> **BOSS NASS:** Yousa doen grand. Jar Jar bringen da Naboo together.
>
> **JAR JAR:** Oh, no, no, no...
>
> **BOSS NASS:** So, wesa maken yousa Bombad General.

Later on, in *The Clone Wars*, Jar Jar returns to Otoh Gunga without issue.

[image: Jar Jar on Otoh Gunga]

Additionally, Boss Lyonie holds Binks's opinion in such high regard that he almost immediately makes up his mind after listening to him. It seems unlikely he would do this if Jar Jar was banished.

> **Yoda:** Senator Amidala, your longtime ally, trapped on an occupied planet, she is.
>
> **Boss Lyonie:** Wesa need some thinking time to respond to deesa news.
>
> **Jar Jar:** Mesa thinking padme would help us, has helped us, big-time! Wesa gots to help her now!
>
> **Boss Lyonie:** Yousa right. Thinking time's-a done!